# Using multiple fonts across pages in Next JS

Tags: import, next.js, google-fonts

I'm used to importing google fonts in css files and then using the `font-family` property. But I want to utilize the ***"built-in automatic self-hosting"*** provided by `@next/font`.

> @next/font includes built-in automatic self-hosting for any font file.

> This new font system also allows you to conveniently use all Google Fonts with performance and privacy in mind. CSS and font files are downloaded at build time and self-hosted with the rest of your static assets. No requests are sent to Google by the browser.

So far I can only import and use multiple fonts in `index.js`. I want to use the same fonts in another page `about.js` without loading the fonts again.

##### How can I import multiple fonts from `@next/font/google` and use them across pages and components?

Is there a way I can attach the fonts to particular classes or selectors?

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using 2 fonts by local and google globaly

```
import { Manrope } from '@next/font/google'
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const akzidenz = localFont({
  weight: '500',
  variable: '--font-akzidenz-grotesk-pro',
  src: '../../public/fonts/Akzidenz-Grotesk-Pro/AkzidenzGroteskPro- 
  MdEx.woff2',
})

const manrope = Manrope({
 weight: '400',
 subsets: [ 'latin' ],
 variable: '--font-manrope',
})

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
 return (
  <main className={`${akzidenz.variable} ${manrope.variable}`}>
   <Component {...pageProps} />
  </main>
 )
}
```

After that you can use in the styling of the application according to the specified variables

Comment: This is how you do it while using tailwind

Comment: can confirm that this is working for Next.js 14 aswell, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We cannot attach `@next/font/google` fonts to particular classes using `font-family` because they have different names when imported.

[image: element image]

---

We can reuse fonts by doing this:

1. Create a separate `utils/fonts.js` file:

```js
import { Exo_2, Noto_Sans } from "@next/font/google";

export const titleFont = Exo_2({
  weight: ["500", "600", "700"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

export const textFont = Noto_Sans({
  weight: ["500", "600", "700"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});
```

2. Import the fonts required in `pages/index.js`:

```js
import { textFont, titleFont } from "../utils/fonts";
```

3. Use them with `className` property:

```js
<main className={styles.main + " " + textFont.className}>
  <h1 className={titleFont.className}>Home Page</h1>
  <p>Hi this is the home page.</p>
</main>
```

---

- You can do the same thing with **local fonts**. Just import them in `fonts.js` and then export their loader functions.
- Using variable names like `textFont` and `titleFont` helps in forming a uniform system.
- You can use the font with other styling classes by simply adding a space in between like this:
  `{styles.main + " " + textFont.className}`

Read documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#reusing-fonts).

Comment: May I ask: The documentation for reusing does not seem to cater for the newer 'app' directory approach of nextjs13, which doesn't use the 'pages' dir. Is there a method with 'app' to make next/font available globally? Or must it be done by importing fonts.js on a component by component basis (which feels too tedious to be correct)?

Comment: I share the same concerns. I've tried in both the layout and template files to load Google fonts via next/font and got an error that fonts must be loaded from modules. I'm sure this is all for performance reasons. I can't imagine having to import a Google font on every page file. I still can't get my head around not having a top-most HOC like _app.js to be able to do global stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I try this method where i can use multiple fonts on my code and apply css on it also without any problem.

Here is my code :

```
//app/page.js

import Image from 'next/image'
import { Poppins} from '@next/font/google'
import { Anton} from '@next/font/google'
import styles from './page.module.css'

const poppins = Poppins({ weight: '400', subsets: ['latin']  })
const anton = Anton({ weight: '400', subsets: ['latin']  })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div  >
        <h1 className={styles.heading}><span className={anton.className}> Hello </span></h1>
      </div>
      <div  >
        <h2 className={styles.heading}><span className={poppins.className}> Hello </span></h2>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

You see i use heading and apply styles on it and after that i can use span in inside the heading tag and apply the fonts that i want to use

Answer (score 0):

I found the Next.js documentation for pages to be unclear when it came to adding multiple fonts globally. However, I managed to solve the issue by injecting the custom CSS variable instead of using a wrapper and className.

```
import { type AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { DM_Sans, Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Head from 'next/head';
import 'styles/globals.css';

const dmSans = DM_Sans({
  weight: ['400', '500', '700'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
});

const inter = Inter({
  weight: ['400', '500'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <style jsx global>{`
        html {
          --dm-sans-font: ${dmSans.style.fontFamily};
          --inter-font: ${inter.style.fontFamily};
        }
      `}</style>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Setting font using css

The way to set style using css is to use **font variables**, you pass
a css variable to the parent of the element you want to use the font in and that css varaible includes the font family

```js
import { Exo_2 } from "@next/font/google"

exo2 = Exo_2({
    weight:"400",
    variable:"--font-exo2"
})

export default function parent() {
    return <div className={exo2.variable}></div>
}
```

### Css

```css
.child {
   font-family: var(--font-exo2);
}
```